# base URL changed while pass the parameters as the second argument laravel 5.2

Tags: url, laravel-5

I have a problem of changed base URL in laravel 5.2 while passing the parameters as second argument to load a page. Like:

```
"/user/24" -> www.xyz.com/user/24
```

while loading the URL my base path for assets changed like:

```
www.xyz.com/public/css/style.css -> www.xyz.com/user/public/css/style.css
```

How to prevent the overriding?

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the problem at laravel 5.2 just mention

```
{{url('/')}} or echo url('/')
```

before the assets link. Like:

```
<link href="{{ url('/') }}/public/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a url helper specifically for assets that you can use; [`asset()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-asset).

This means you don't need to specify public as part of the URL you create either, meaning you could just link your stylesheet (and any other resource) like so:

`<link href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />`

This is much cleaner and easy to use than manually using the `url()` helper.